# two short questions about pointers and references

Tags: c++, pointers

1. consider this code:

   ```
   double *pi;
   double j;
   pi = &j;
   pi[3] = 5;
   ```

I don't understand how is that possible that I can perform the last line here.
I set pi to the reference of j, which is a double variable, and not a double [] variable. so how is this possible that I can perform an array commands on it?

2. consider this code:

   ```
   char *c = "abcdefg";
   std::cout << &(c[3]) << endl;
   ```

the output is "defg". I expected that I will get a reference output because I used &, but instead I got the value of the char * from the cell position to the end. why is that?

Comment: There aren't any references involved, just pointers and addresses.

Comment: I would suggest reading a beginners C++ book to learn the basics and this will all become clear.

Comment: You need to read a good C++ book first. These are very basic question.

Comment: There's no such thing as "array commands". Arrays have no commands. You're simply doing __pointer arithmetic__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate questions here.

1. A pointer is sometimes used to point to an array or buffer in memory. Therefore it supports the `[]` syntax. In this case, using `pi[x]` where x is not 0 is invalid as you are not pointing to an array or buffer.
2. Streams have an overload for `char` pointers to treat them as a C-style string, and not output their address. That is what is happening in your second case. Try `std::cout << static_cast<const void *>(&(c[3])) << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Pointers and arrays go hand in hand in C (sort of...)

`pi[3]` is the same as `*(pi + 3)`. In your code however this leads to Undefined Behavior as you create a pointer outside an object bounds.

Also be careful as `*` and `&` are different operators depending on in which kind of expression the appear.

Answer (score 0):

1. That is undefined behavior. C++ allows you to do things you ought not to.
2. There are special rules for `char*`, because it is often used as the beginning of a string. If pass a `char*` to `cout`, it will print whatever that points to as characters, and stop when it reaches a '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a few main things here:

1. A pointer is what it is, it points to a location in the memory. So therefore, a pointer can be an array if you whish.
2. If you are working with pointers (dangerous at times), this complicates things. You are writing on p, which is a pointer to a memory location. So, even though you have not allocated the memory, you can access the memory as an array and write it. But this gives us the question you are asking. How can this be? well, the simple answer is that you are accessing a zone of memory where the variable you have created has absolutely no control, so you could possibly be stepping on another variable (if you have others) or simply just writting on memory that has not been used yet.

I dont't understand what you are asking in the second question, maybe you could explain a little more? Thanks.

Comment: "So therefore, a pointer can be an array if you whish (sic)." doesn't follow.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of this code...

```
double *pi;
double j;
pi = &j;
pi[3] = 5;
```

... is the syntactic equivalent to *(pi + 3) = 5. There is no difference in how a compiler views a double[] variable and a double* variable.

Although the above code will compile, it will cause a memory error. Here is safe code that illustrates the same concepts...

```
double *pi = new double[5]; // allocate 5 places of int in heap
double j;
pi[3] = 5; // give 4th place a value of 5
delete pi; // erase allocated memory
pi = &j; // now get pi to point to a different memory location
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how is that possible that I can perform the last
>   line here. I set pi to the reference of j

Actually, you're setting your *pointer* pi, to point to the **memory address** of j.

When you do pi[3], you're using a non-array variable as an array. While valid c++, it is inherently dangerous. You run the risk of overwriting the memory of other variables, or even access memory outside your process, which will result in the operating system killing your program.

When that's said, pi[3] means you're saying "give me the slot third down from the memory location of pi". So you're not touching pi itself, but an offset.

If you want to use arrays, declare them as such:

```
double pi[5]; //This means 5 doubles arrayed aside each other, hence the term "array".
```

Appropos arrays, in c++ it's usually better to not use raw arrays, instead use vectors(there are other types of containers):

```
vector<double> container;
container.push(5.25); //"push" means you add a variable to the vector.
```

Unlike raw arrays, a container such as a vector, will keep it's size internally, so if you've put 5 doubles in it, you can call container.size(), which will return 5. Useful in for loops and the like.

About your second question, you're effectively returning a reference to a substring of your "abcdefg" string.

&([3]) means "give me a string, starting from the d". Since c-style strings(which is what char* is called) add an extra NULL at the end, any piece of code that takes these as arguments(such as cout) will keep reading memory until they stumble upon the NULL(aka a 0). The NULL terminates the string, meaning it marks the end of the data.

Appropos, c-style strings are the only datatype that behaves like an array, without actually being one. This also means they are dangerous. Personally I've never had any need to use one. I recommend using modern strings instead. These newer, c++ specific variables are both safe to use, as well as easier to use. Like vectors, they are containers, they keep track of their size, and they resize automatically. Observe:

```
string test = "abcdefg";
cout<<test.size()<<endl;//prints 7, the number of characters in the array.
test.append("hijklmno");//appends the string, AND updates the size, so subsequent calls will now return 15.
```